# Hooks for agenda

Tags: org-mode, hooks

I need to run a function every time I run `org-agenda`. However, I need it to run prior to the agenda. I wasn't able to find any hooks for the agenda command in the documentation. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps if you are a little more specific about what you would like to achieve, you can obtain a more specific answer.  You can advise `org-agenda` to run your custom function first (using `advice` ...), or you can simply create a new function:  `(defun my-org-agenda () "Doc-string." (interactive "P") (message "hello-world") (call-interactively 'org-agenda))`  In that example, replace `(message "hello-world")` with your function that you want to run first in time.  [CAVEAT:  I have not tested/attempted to pass a prefix arg to `org-agenda` using the aforementioned example, but it *may* suffice]

Comment: `org-agenda-mode-hook` is run from `org-agenda-mode` which in turn is run from `org-agenda-prepare` which is run by `org-agenda-list` before the agenda is created (and while the buffer is still writable). If that's not early enough, then @lawlist's suggestions for a wrapper function or a `before` advice would be the only solutions I can see.

Comment: @Drew Sorry about that. Won't do it again

Comment: @NickD this was what I was looking for. Thanks. I just needed to run a function before every run of `org-agenda`. I you provide an answer to the question I will mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Done - glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org-agenda-mode-hook` is run from `org-agenda-mode` which in turn is run from `org-agenda-prepare` which is run by `org-agenda-list` before the agenda is created (and while the buffer is still writable). If that's early enough, you can add your function to the hook with

```
 (add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 'my-function)
```

If that's not early enough, then @lawlist's suggestions for a wrapper function or a before advice would be the only solutions I can see.